# Creating a hardware interface for a physical sensor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to use ros2_control to create interfaces with my robot.

I have replicated the `rrbot_system_with_sensor` example in `ros-controls/ros2_control_demos`.

I have created a subclass of `hardware_interface::SystemInterface`, and can see that my code is getting loaded and executed. I can see the sensor and command interfaces in `list_hardware_interfaces`, but its all just fake data. This is a good start, but I am stumped on how to create the actual hardware interface wrapper.

For context, our sensors and multiple of our motor drivers are connected to the RaspberryPi as Serial devices (USB/USART) and have custom protocols. I can write the logic layer, but I do not know how to implement the transport layer compatable with `ros2_control`.

So I have two primary questions:
Am I on the right track to subclass `hardware_interface::SystemInterface`?

More importantly, how do I actually communicate with the hardware in a realtime-safe fashion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386827/creating-a-hardware-interface-for-a-physical-sensor/) by [theunkn0wn1](https://answers.ros.org/users/85104/theunkn0wn1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-19**:
Have you read this: https://ros-controls.github.io/control.ros.org/getting_started.html

**Comment by [theunkn0wn1](https://answers.ros.org/users/85104/theunkn0wn1/) on 2021-09-19**:
I have. All of that documentation is abstract and doesn't appear to clearly convey how a user would actually implement these concepts in software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're still looking for an answer I can try to help out. Although it would be a bit easier if you could share some code.

If I understand correctly, you created a class derived from SystemInterface, and you're looking for where to put the code which will actually communicate with hardware, fill states with real data from some sensors, and to pass on commands to an actuator?

You can take a look here for a couple of implementations: https://github.com/dignakov/ros2_control_demo_drivers. I haven't updated this repo in a while, so it doesn't match the latest `ros2_control` master branch so you should still follow the examples there if something doesn't agree, but it should give you an idea of how to set this up (I will update everything at some point soon...)

You can (or at least this is how I did it):

(1) Put put all of the variables/classes/structs you need to talk to your hardware as private members of your class.

(2) Configure them (along with getting parameters and everything else) in `configure()`

(3) Initialize the communication in `start()` and make sure you're getting data from the robot that makes sense.

(4) Fill in the `read()` and `write()` functions to read data from your sensor and fill in the state, and fill in commands which will be forwarded to the hardware.

(5) `stop()` can also be important to get your hardware into some reasonable state.

Take a look here, the Kuka version is probably a bit closer to what you're doing:
https://github.com/dignakov/ros2_control_demo_drivers/blob/master/ros2_control_kuka_demo_driver/src/kuka_system_position_only.cpp

---

Originally posted by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) with karma: 66 on 2021-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [theunkn0wn1](https://answers.ros.org/users/85104/theunkn0wn1/) on 2021-09-30**:
This helped me greatly, thank you!

**Comment by [bmagyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/89958/bmagyar/) on 2021-11-29**:
Don't forget to mark the answer correct to show others you are happy with it